# When you want to ask someone to meet with another person to define who is the liar

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, expressions

Let's assume that someone is telling something lie about you and claims that what he says is someone else's statements about you. All the stuff he says, seem to be wrong regarding you and you want to prove the speaker that these all are false and tou have not said/done what they are attributing you. What would you say when you are going to ask the speaker **"let's make a face to face meeting** and raise the matter so that everything could get clear and the speaker could find out that you were right and all the statements about you have been wrong, and subsequently the liar could be found."

**Example:**

> **A)** Tedd, yesterday, I was talking to JJ. He said that you've pretended that I have taken a book from the library theree months ago and I didn't taken it back to the library again! Is it right?! 
>   **B)** What?! That's just a bullshit. I have never said that Tom! 
>   **A)** Are you sure Tedd? 
>   **B)** Yea; **let's bring it face to face.**

Or maybe, Tom himself can suggest such a thing! He can say:

> Are you ready **to bring it face to face**?

I need to know what do you usually say in current, natural English in this specific sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can simple say:

> "Let's talk about it".

So you could say:

> "Let's talk about it face to face"

which means in person, not on the phone or whatever.